# Program to change the BPM of several MP3s at once

Tags: music, mp3

I'm looking for a program or web-service that

- can change the BPM of several MP3s at once

And if possible:

- BPM should be as accurate as possible (3-decimal accuracy or better)
- free
- works on Windows 7

Right now I use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), its accuracy over 3-decimal but I have to change the BPM of each MP3 one by one, loading each track and using the GUI to change the tempo:

[image]

Comment: I assume you want to apply the same percentage to multiple files?

Comment: @nidunc actually I'd prefer having MP3s converted to the same target BPM.

Comment: Do all files have different source BPMs?

Comment: @nidunc most of them yes

Comment: Ah... This is tricky... With Audacity you can batch convert the files, but only if they have pretty much the same source BPM (you have to specify both the to and from bpm, otherwise nothing happens), so that probably isn't an option